# Connect(control) Kodi Between Rooms?

Tags: kodi

Hello I am trying to work out how to set kodi up on my smart TV. My main problem lies with the TV being on the wall in another room too far away from power sources. She has sky installed and that was situated in the other room and with a HDMI lead fed under to floorboards to the other room by a professional someone or other. I am unable to feed another HDMI lead along the line.

Is there a way I could connect kodi by some other means to the TV? I am not really up on these things.

At the moment I have the kodi box in another room and I have to switch the sky lead to the kodi box to use. Also this means you have to be in the other room.

Can anyone suggest a way for me to get kodi working on the tv and be able to operate it via remote control?

Answer (score 2):

I use Kodi on all of my TVs through an amazon fire stick. Most smart TVs have a USB on the back of the TV that can power the fire stick while its plugged into the HDMI so you wouldn't have to worry about power. I have a Sony bravia that will control the fire stick as long as I am on the input the fire stick is plugged into so no need for an additional remote.

Answer (score 1):

To start off this is the wrong place to ask. This is a Q and A platform for programming questions and coding related questions.

To give you an answer though because I'm not a dick the best way to do it would be using a NAS. You would have two Kodi boxes but one media store.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which device do you use.
In my case, I installed Kodi on my Raspberry Pi(RPi) and TV and RPi are connected with HDMI. My TV is Samsung SmartTV, which supports HDMI-CEC. So, RPI can get RCU Key input from TV.
(HDMI-CEC allows devices connected to your TV through HDMI ports to communicate back and forth with your TV. )

In addition, you can customize keymaps for remotes in GUI by using the community Keymap Editor add-on.

https://kodi.wiki/view/Keymap

Check your TV supports HDMI-CEC, first.